# Flutter: How can I let the app keep using the app's functions when the app is in the background?

Tags: flutter

I want to allow some functions (such as GPS tracking, and recording wifi names) to run in the background. Can someone provide some solution with or without any plugin? Which one will be more difficult to implement? Thank you.

Comment: I implemented GPS tracking by using a geolocator plugin, which can receive the position data and update the position.

Comment: How can I call the geolocator function in the background to allow it keep to receiving updated location data when the app running in the background? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package

https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

```dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point') // Mandatory if the App is obfuscated or using Flutter 3.1+
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
    print("Native called background task: $task"); //simpleTask will be emitted here.
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() {
  Workmanager().initialize(
    callbackDispatcher, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
    isInDebugMode: true // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
  );
Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
    "periodic-task-identifier", 
    "simplePeriodicTask", 
    // When no frequency is provided the default 15 minutes is set.
    // Minimum frequency is 15 min. Android will automatically change your frequency to 15 min if you have configured a lower frequency.
    frequency: Duration(minutes: 10),
)
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Create a top level function and you can schedule a work to be done at the background